# How To Prevent Replication Failure

Tags: mysql, replication, errors

If I become a MySQL DBA, will I had to deal all day with those kind of issues or do you have tips to prevent from breaking the whole replication?

I received this message because I removed manually the database, and after that the php script remove it.

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 1133`
Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query.`
```

Answer (score -3):

I found this.

```
slave-skip-errors=1133
```

Comment: Don't do it if you care about data consistency between the master and slave.

Comment: To prevent errors like that put the slave in read_only mode and make sure MySQL clients don't have SUPER privilege.

Comment: to find and fix inconsistencies use pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync tools

Comment: To skip a single, *known* query, issue: `SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER:=1; START SLAVE;`